# How to find the screenshots folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm doing some stuff to share a hair style for Jinryuu's DBC/NC mods, but I need pictures of it. I haven't been able to find the screenshots folder, or even the .minecraft folder! I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Search %appdata% in the Windows Search Bar, then go to the .minecraft folder (should be near the top) and in that folder there should be a screenshots folder!

You could also put this in the directory bar:

C:\Users*USER*\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\screenshots

Replace *USER* with your Windows Authentication username.

Also, if necessary, change C: to whichever drive you're using (ie: C:, D:, A: etc.)

This should bring you directly to the Minecraft Screenshots folder.

Comment: I haven't actually tested it for the URL bar, but in case someone does not know their user, they can use `C:\Users\%USERNAME%`. It works with batch and the command prompt, but could work for users too